# Can't run bbb from CL

Tags: macos, node.js, backbone.js, npm, yeoman

I'm trying to install bbb but am having problems in the CL. I have managed to download the packages using npm (although I had to use sudo - is that normal?) but when I try to use the bbb command I get a "command not found" error.
I've tried updating my $PATH with where I think the modules are, but that doesn't seem to help.

It looks as though bbb has been downloaded to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` so that is what I've tried adding to my $PATH.

Any help would be gratefully received. Especially because I want to try Yeoman next and I'm afraid I might run into the same problems.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.4